# Use sed to change date string by pattern

Tags: json, bash, sed

I need to use sed (or awk) to change a date string inside a JSON file named test.json. The date format in the file has the following format: *"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"*. I would like to change this format to *"yyyymmddHHMMSS"*. I tried with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
sed -ie "s/'[[digit]]\-[[digit]]\-[[digit]]\s[[digit]]\:[[digit]]\:[[digit]]'/[[digit]][[digit]][[digit]][[digit]][[digit]][[digit]]/g" test.json
```

testing from command line:
echo 2017-03-16 08:30:00 | sed "s/'[[digit]]-[[digit]]-[[digit]]\s[[digit]]:[[digit]]:[[digit]]'/[[digit]][[digit]][[digit]][[digit]][[digit]][[digit]]/g"

I also tried:

```
sed -ie "s/*\-*\-*\-*\s*\:*\:*/******/g" test.json
```

testing from command line:

```
echo 2017-03-16 08:30:00 | sed "s/*\-*\-*\-*\s*\:*\:*/******/g"
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
 sed -Ei 's/\b([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})\b/\1\2\3\4\5\6/g' test.json
```

`-E` option, allows extended regular expresssions

`\b` - means a word boundary